# Read binary values (such 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011...) as an array of digits

Tags: vba, ms-access, binary

I am in search of a solution for the following task:

General environment: I am working on a toolbox of VBA functions to process data in an Access database of educational offers. This includes various  string operations and operations with database fields mostly via SQL.

In one of my functions, I have to deal with different states of four database fields in a row, their values being NULL or not NULL. As each field can be either NULL or not NULL, we have 16 possible situations:

0-0-0-0, 0-0-0-1, 0-0-1-0, 0-0-1-1 and so on,

which is obviously quite the same as:

`0000`, `0001`, `0010`, `0011`, `0100`, ..., `1111`, i.e. binary representation of decimal 0-15.

In order to not hard code every single case, I want make use of the binary representations of numbers 0-15 by counting up from 0 to 15.

In pseudocode:

```
i = 0
For i = 0 To 15
  arrX(): 0000
  StateOfField01 = arrX(0) [which is 0, in this case]
  StateofField02 = arrX(1) [dito]
  StateOfField03 = arrX(2) [dito] 
  StateofField04 = arrX(3) [dito]
  Do something with the fields, depending on their state
  i = i + 1
Next i
```

So far I am happy with my idea, but there is one thing I have no idea how to solve:

***How can I get from the binary representations of i an array containing four digits each?***

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109260

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which will convert a Decimal number to Binary String.

```
Public Function GetBinary(Number As Long) As String
'********************
'Code Courtesy of
'  Paul Eugin
'********************
    Dim resultStr As String, nLen As Integer

    Do While Number > 0
        resultStr = resultStr & (Number Mod 2)
        Number = Int(Number / 2)
    Loop

    GetBinary = Format(StrReverse(resultStr), "0000")

End Function
```

The function will take in a "Number" as argument for which you want to find the Binary equivalent. The Format function at the end of the code will make sure the return would be a minimum of 4 literal representation. So if you pass the example,

```
? GetBinary(5)
0101
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on PaulFrancis' input, I found the following solution answering my proper needs.

Important additions are 1) "ByVal" for the argument in the call so that the function can be called from inside another procedure whose for-next counter should be preserved; 2) a test for "Number" being 0 which was not covered previously.

```
Public Function GetBinary(ByVal Number As Integer) As String

Dim resultStr As String

If Number = 0 Then
    resultStr = "0"
Else
    Do While Number > 0
        resultStr = resultStr & (Number Mod 2)
        Number = Int(Number / 2)
    Loop
End If

GetBinary = Format(StrReverse(resultStr), "0000")

End Function
'-----------------------------------
Public Sub TestBinaryToString()
'Purpose: Testing the GetBinary() function: 
'output will be displayed in the Immediate Window

Dim i As Integer
Dim strBin As String

For i = 0 To 15
    strBin = GetBinary(i)
    Debug.Print i; " --> "; strBin
Next i

End Sub
```